# WARNING: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

We are getting the following error when using Oracle 11g ojdbc6.jar:

```
WARNING: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
javax.management.StandardMBean.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;Z)V
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDiagnosabilityMBean.<init>(OracleDiagnosabilityMBean.java:34)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:342)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:199)
```

After investigating from many forums and blogs, we have not found any final solutions yet. So, we want to share the workaround way here.

Answer (score 6):

According Oracle document, The JDBC diagnosability management feature introduces an MBean, oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDiagnosabilityMBean. This MBean provides means to enable and disable JDBC logging, you can find it here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm.

And, the driver uses java.util.logging for logging purpose, actually in our cases we don't really need to use that info, so decide to disable the log and there is NO warning happen anymore.

How to disable the log for the driver (oracle.jdbc):

- As default, JRE use the default properties file in JRE_HOME\lib\logging.properties, so edit the file and adding this info:

  - oracle.jdbc.level=OFF
- Or configuring your own properties log file for java.util.logging

  - java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/YourConfig.properties
  - Add oracle.jdbc.level=OFF to YourConfig.properties

It works for us, don't get any WANRING error above.

Comment: This may not solve the problem for everyone, as it did not for me. Link to Oracle download is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.  I don't know if my environment is the same.

In my environment, I'm using both jdbc and jboss jars in the same application.
I believe, but did not verify, that something in the jboss jars is hooking
into the class loader and causing the issue.

I got around the issue by only loading the ojdbc driver jar, creating my
database instance, and then loading the jboss jars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Maven and my project was using `log4j 1.2.15`. For whatever reason, `1.2.15` has dependencies on `jms 1.1`, `jmxtools 1.2.1`, and **`jmxri 1.2.1`**.

`jmxri 1.2.1` contains a version of `StandardMBean` with a constructor that takes a `StandardMBean` (not `java.lang.Class`). While I did not do extensive testing to confirm this hypothesis, I believe that this is the version of the class that was being used, and the ultimate cause of the error.

It seems as though `log4j 1.2.14` doesn't have those dependencies. So I backed down to `1.2.14`, and took them out.