# Oracle: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean

Tags: oracle11g, mbeans, oracleclient, oracleexception

I am trying to install OracleClient 11g and initially i had a issue regarding JDK compatibility.

**Error:**

[image]

so i ended up uninstalling JDK 7 (64bit) and reinstalled JDK 6 (32bit) and edited sqldeveloper.conf for SetJavaHome.

```
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31
```

Now, once i click sqldeveloper.exe it loads up and throws an error as mentioned below

**Error (i):**

[image]

**Error (ii):**

[image]

I tried similar issue [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191054/warning-error-while-registering-oracle-jdbc-diagnosability-mbean) in stackoverflow but didn't help much. So any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't solve the problem but found out an alternative way.

Install JDK1.6 ( 32bit)
Install Oracle Client (32bit)

**Note:** even if u have OS 64bit, try installing 32bit JDK & Oracle client and u should not face this error.